# How to find Correlation of a grayscale image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

There is an image A of fixed size 256*256. I am able to find correlation between horizontally and vertically adjacent pixels. But I am not understanding how exactly to randomly select 4096 pairs of two diagonally adjacent pixels from the image, calculate their correlation co-efficient and then plot the distribution of these diagonally adjacent pixels.

```
xed = A(1:end-1,1:end-1);  % All but the last row and column
yed = A(2:end,2:end);      % All but the first row and column

randIndex = randperm(numel(xed));  % A random permutation of the integers from 1 to numel(x)
randIndex = randIndex(1:4096);     % Pick the first 4096 indices
xRand = xod(randIndex);            % 4096 random values from x
yRand = yod(randIndex);            % The corresponding 4096 values from y

% Compute the Correlation coefficient of x and y
red_xy = corrcoef(xRand(:),yRand(:));
```

Same algorithm is used to encrypt both color and grayscale images. For color images it is applied to RGB planes separately and for grayscale only once. Diagonal correlation coefficient almost zero is obtained in case of color image. In grayscale I want to know if I am going wrong in calculating correlation coefficient.

Comment: @PaulR I have tried randomly selecting pixels horizontally and vertical and calculating correlation co-efficient. I have used one of the answer given by gnovice on stackoverfllow itself. I used it for color image and got satisfactory results. I don't know where am I going wrong in applying it to grayscale image.

Comment: @PaulR Same algorithm is used to encrypt both color and grayscale images. For color images it is applied to RGB planes separately and for grayscale only once. Diagonal correlation coefficient almost zero is obtained in case of color image. In grayscale I want to know if I am going wrong in calculating correlation coefficient.

Comment: Again, you're posting relevant information in comments - move this into the question - it will help people to better answer your question.

Comment: Are you sure you have actually extracted one colour plane at a time correctly? Have you looked at the values in `xRand` and `yRand` to see whether they look at all sensible? Is the fact that the code here says `xod` and `yod` instead of `xed` and `yed` simply an error in transcription here, or could that be the cause of your problem?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan The code above is the one I tried for the gray scale image. For color image I have made use of the code provided on stackoverflow only. The above code is the modification of the same for the gray scale image.

Comment: OK. So (1) can you post the corresponding colour code? and (2) what makes you think there is something wrong with this code? When I run exactly your code above, with the only difference being that I replaced `xod` and `yod` with `xed` and `yed`, I get very plausible-looking correlation coefficients.

Comment: What output do you get for what input? (You can at least describe the input even if you can't provide it explicitly. Or generate it synthetically and post the code that does that.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Thanks a lot! I got it. It was my mistake. I also replaced xod and yod with xed and yed and got the required results! Actually the algorithm code is very big, so I could not spot the small silly mistake. Many thanks you showed me my mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This was originally in (my) comments, but turns out actually to be the answer. I'm making it into an actual answer that can be accepted as recommended at, e.g., https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-to-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments.)

The problem is that your partial arrays are defined like this

```
xed = A(1:end-1,1:end-1);
```

with names `xed` and `yed`, but used like this

```
xRand = xod(randIndex);
```

with names `xod` and `yod`. Presumably you have other variables, defined elsewhere, with those names, which is why your code does something wrong instead of failing with an obvious error.

There's a more general moral here: you can reduce the risk of this kind of error by giving your variables longer, more informative and more distinctive names that can't be turned into one another by single-character typos :-).

Comment: Thanks! I will take care of it henceforth.

Comment: You should also accept the answer, since it does in fact answer your question. (Of course I have an ulterior motive for saying this: it will give me more SO reputation points.)

Answer (score 2):

I hope that is true, and everyone is helpful. I'm sorry for my English.

```
%usage [k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,k6]=resim_korelasyon('lennagri.bmp','lenagrisifreli1.bmp',0);
%k1,k2,k3 Original Image correlation coefficient
%k4,k5,k6 encrypted image correlation coefficient
%color  ==> 0 gray , 1 RGB
%kyatayO,kdikeyO,kkosegenO,kyatayI,kdikeyI,kkosegenI  correlation coefficients

function [kyatayO,kdikeyO,kkosegenO,kyatayI,kdikeyI,kkosegenI]=resim_korelasyon(ImageOriginal,ImageEncrypted,color) 
 %Original Image
 I=imread(ImageOriginal);
 A = im2double(I);
 %encrypted image
 I2=imread(ImageEncrypted);
 A2 = im2double(I2);

 if (color==0)
    %For GRAY image
    %==================================================
    %Original Image
    %horizontal
    x1 = A(:,1:end-1);  
    y1 = A(:,2:end);
    kyatayO=hesap(x1,y1);
    %Vertical
    x2 = A(1:end-1,:);  
    y2 = A(2:end,:);    
    kdikeyO=hesap(x2,y2);
    %diagonal
    x3 = A(1:end-1,1:end-1);  
    y3 = A(2:end,2:end);     
    kkosegenO=hesap(x3,y3);

    %==================================================
    %for encrypted image
    %horizontal
    x4 = A2(:,1:end-1);  
    y4 = A2(:,2:end);
    kyatayI=hesap(x4,y4);
    %Vertical
    x5 = A2(1:end-1,:);  
    y5 = A2(2:end,:);    
    kdikeyI=hesap(x5,y5);
    %diagonal
    x6 = A2(1:end-1,1:end-1);  
    y6 = A2(2:end,2:end);     
    kkosegenI=hesap(x6,y6);
    %==================================================
    %graphics
    h=figure;
    subplot(3,2,1),grafik(x1,y1),title('Horizontal');
    subplot(3,2,3),grafik(x2,y2),title('Vertical');
    subplot(3,2,5),grafik(x3,y3),title('Diagonal');
    subplot(3,2,2),grafik(x4,y4),title('Horizontal');
    subplot(3,2,4),grafik(x5,y5),title('Vertical');
    subplot(3,2,6),grafik(x6,y6),title('Diagonal');
    saveas(h,'correlationGray.jpg');
 end

 if(color==1) %For RGB
            %==================================================
            %Orjinal Görüntü İçin
            %Yatay korelasyon
            x1 = A(:,1:end-1,1);  %RED değerine göre hesaplanır. 1 RED 2 GREEN 3 BLUE
            y1 = A(:,2:end,1); 
            kyatayO=hesap(x1,y1);
            %dikey korelasyon
            x2 = A(1:end-1,:,1);  
            y2 = A(2:end,:,1);  
            kdikeyO=hesap(x2,y2);
            %diagonal / çapraz kolerasyon (Sağ üst köşeden sola)
            x3 = A(1:end-1,1:end-1,1);  
            y3 = A(2:end,2:end,1);  
            kkosegenO=hesap(x3,y3);
            %======================================================
            %İşlenmiş Görüntü İçin
            %Yatay korelasyon
            x4 = A2(:,1:end-1,1);  %RED değerine göre hesaplanır. 1 RED 2 GREEN 3 BLUE
            y4 = A2(:,2:end,1); 
            kyatayI=hesap(x4,y4);
            %dikey korelasyon
            x5 = A2(1:end-1,:,1);  
            y5 = A2(2:end,:,1);  
            kdikeyI=hesap(x5,y5);
            %diagonal / çapraz kolerasyon (Sağ üst köşeden sola)
            x6 = A2(1:end-1,1:end-1,1);  
            y6 = A2(2:end,2:end,1);  
            kkosegenI=hesap(x6,y6);
            %==================================================
            %grafikler çizdiriliyor ve kaydediliyor
            h=figure;
            subplot(3,2,1),grafik(x1,y1),title('Horizontal');
            subplot(3,2,3),grafik(x2,y2),title('Vertical');
            subplot(3,2,5),grafik(x3,y3),title('Diagonal');
            subplot(3,2,2),grafik(x4,y4),title('Horizontal');
            subplot(3,2,4),grafik(x5,y5),title('Vertical');
            subplot(3,2,6),grafik(x6,y6),title('Diagonal');
            saveas(h,'correlationRGB.jpg');
 end  
end

function [correlation_coefficient]=hesap(x,y)
    correlation_coefficient = corrcoef(x(:),y(:));
end

function grafik(x,y)
    randIndex = randperm(numel(x));  
    randIndex = randIndex(1:2000);   
    xRand = x(randIndex);            
    yRand = y(randIndex); 
    xRand = xRand * 256;
    yRand = yRand * 256;  
    scatter(xRand,yRand,'.');
end
```