# Saving Encrypted Image with orginal size

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a program in matlab for Encrypting image with size [512,512] .after running the program I have matrix  with size [512,512](Encrypted Image )but when I want to save Encrypting image in my disk image size is changing.Is there any way to saving image with original size?

Comment: Most image formats use compression techniques to lessen the file size, and compression doesn't work well on encrypted data because it's less predictable. Your expectation of being able to save at the same size may be unrealistic.

Comment: Actually i found a code for Calculate Correlation between adjacent pixels (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396740/how-to-find-correlation-of-a-grayscale-image)  . program needs image and Encrypted Image for inputs .I thought may be because of difference of sizes the result is not  
reliable